# Creating a directory and storing a javascript file in drupal 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, drupal-7, directory

I am facing confusion in creating a directory. 
I am trying to install a module in drupal 7 with the name - View Slideshow. It requires some prior installations.

Here is the website that gives the instructions ->

https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/modules/views-slideshow/installation-requirements

Here it is written that ->

Create a directory within sites/all/libraries named jquery.cycle and save the jQuery.Cycle JavaScript file there.

So does it mean i need to create a folder with the name jquery.cycle and store the code of jQuery.Cycle JavaScript file in the jquery.cycle folder with the same name as jquery.cycle ?

It would become

```
 sites/all/libraries/jquery.cycle/jquery.cycle ?
```

Please help . I don't understand what will be the name of the folder and what will be the name of the file inside that folder ?

Comment: Just making sure, do you not have composer or drush as available options?

Comment: ok so before all this , i need to run the composer / drush. Isn't it ? in the via root in my drupal site console ?

Comment: You don't have to run composer / drush, but it does make installing a whole lot easier. So if you have those available on the project, definitely install the module using either of those. The manual installation is just there for people who have neither composer or drush as available tools.

Comment: Still if you can help me  with manual installation to be on a safer side

Comment: 1. Do exactly what the instructions say. 2, If it works, stop. 3. If it doesn't, try one of the other things. Should take a couple of minutes to find out. But really, use an installer like @Lesleyvdp says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer You question It was all documented there clearly, but for your understanding I can sort it down.

**This is for manual installation only:**

**1.** Make sure all the three required modules are installed.

- [Views - 7.x-3.x](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) version, Make sure your are using `3.x` version.
- [Ctools](https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools)
- [Libraries API](https://www.drupal.org/project/libraries)

Navigate into `sites/all/libraries` this should be default drupal folder structure.

If you don't have a folder like above create one.

**2.** Inside the folder `libraries` you need to create individual folders like `jQuery.Cycle` `jquery.easing` note these are individual folder names.

It should look like:

`sites/all/libraries/jQuery.Cycle`

`sites/all/libraries/jquery.easing`

> Imagine you are inside `sites/all/libraries/jQuery.Cycle` folder

Raw javascript file can be copied from the link they have given [jQuery.Cycle JavaScript file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/malsup/cycle/3.0.3/jquery.cycle.all.js) copy the whole page and paste into a
**file** This file should be named `jQuery.Cycle.js`

**Finally you end up like this:** `sites/all/libraries/jQuery.Cycle/jQuery.Cycle.js`

If you prefer to get all plugin files instead of only javascript files, you can follow the links to get all files.

- [jQuery Cycle plugin](https://github.com/malsup/cycle)
- [jQuery Easing plugin](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/)
- [jQuery Pause plugin](https://github.com/tobia/Pause)
- [jQuery Hover Intent plugin](https://github.com/briancherne/jquery-hoverIntent)
- [JSON2 plugin](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/)